# IDE/SATA HD not showing

Tags: hard-drive

my computer has been running 4 hard discs, one just has ubuntu os on it, another is an IDE drive with SATA interface, and the other two are large SATA drives. All was working well. Then I lost the IDE drive. Doesn't show up anywhere. GParted shows nothing at all, in fact GParted won't run, even reinstalled it doesn't run.

I changed the C: to run MS XP Pro, and managed to get back one of the large (0.5TB) SATA drives, and it shows C:, D: and E: but no IDE/SATA HD.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any output when trying to run GParted?

Comment: I re-downloaded GParted, now it runs, but only detects the two large HD's. However, I have tried another IDE drive in the position that has the IDE to SATA interface, and that can't be detected either, even though I know for sure it works (it contains my MS XPpro OS. Just tried to run GParted again, and it won't run!